# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, instance

I was trying to do some code when I spotted this error. I first define the `player` class with a `name` a `param1` and `param2`.
When I run the `game` function and i try to create an instance of the `player`
 class inside, I get the `UnboundLocalError` error. Here is my code:

```
class player(object):

    def __init__ (self, name, param1 = None, param2 = None):

        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.name = name

def game(n = int(raw_input('How many players? '))):

    playerList = [] 

    for x in range(n):
        playerList.append(player(raw_input('Player %i: ' %(x+1))))

    for player in playerList:
        player.param1 = int(raw_input('%s, how many do you predict? ' %(player.name.upper())))
```

So basically, my problem is that python doesn't let me create an instance of a class inside a function. I have searched a lot, but I have not found what I was searching for. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Default variables are calculated during parsing, so it's not a good idea to add `raw_input` inside function arguments, as it is going to be called even if you don't run this function ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the variable name `player` in `for player in playerList`, but your class is also named `player`.  Since you assign a value to that name (in the for loop), Python treats it as a local variable, so you can't access the global class of that name.

The best solution is to change your class name to `Player` with a capital P.  The convention in Python is for classes to start with an uppercase letter.

(The reason the error occurs on the earlier line is that Python decides which variables are local when parsing the function.  Since you used `player` as the target of the for loop, it is marked as local, but at the time you first access it, when trying to access the class, no value is assigned to that local variable.)

Comment: The error is in this line `playerList.append(player(raw_input('Player %i: ' %(x+1))))`

Comment: @SukritKalra local variables are decided when the function definition is parsed, so for `player`  the function will not access the global scope, it thinks that `player` is a local variable.

Comment: Oh yes. Forgot about that. Sorry. :)

Comment: Wow... I knew it was something stupid... Thanks for the quick answer!